# Can an image be displayed in a cell (not in the first column) using Tkinter's TreeView widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm using `Tkinter` to create a UI for a multiplayer launcher I created for the PC game SimCity 4.

[image: SC4MP Launcher]

Ideally, I would like this last column to display a different image depending on the rating of the server (ie. >1 and <2 display one image, >2 and <3 display another, etc.).

Is there any way to insert an image in a Tkinter `TreeView` cell that is NOT in the first column?

Even hacky solutions?

I've done some searching on the internet and haven't found a solution.

All the code can be found at https://github.com/kegsmr/sc4mp-client

Comment: `treeview` can't add images in other columns. I found [TkTreeCtrl](https://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/) and maybe it could do this but it is for `Tcl/Tk` and it would need to execute code in `tcl`. But maybe you will find other module for `Python`.

Comment: I found [TkinterTreeCtrl](https://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: you can always use `.grid()` to simulate own table. And then you can put `Label` with `Image` in any place.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the help. I'll look into that `TkTreeCtrl` thing. If not I might just have to make my own table like you said.